# find partial matching two files in perl

Tags: perl

I want to write a Perl program. The first input file is 2 columns of text. The first column is a label and the second column is the search string. The second input file also has 2 columns. The first column is a label and the second column is the text to be searched. For example, according to the second columns, John (in the file1) is more similar to Johni in file2 than John.

file1

```
John AABBBCCCDEE
Jam  WWQQQQQQQERRRTTTTTT
```

file2

```
Jami    EWWQQQQQQQERRRTTTTTTTTTT
Johni   AAAAABBBCCCDEEEEEEHHHHHH
Mark    WWWCCVVVVVVFFFFFFFTTTTTT
ROB     ##@@@########VVVVVVVVVVV
John    WWADFRWSSSSSSDDDDDqqqqqq
```

output

```
Jami    EWWQQQQQQQERRRTTTTTTTTTT    Jam  WWQQQQQQQERRRTTTTTT
Johni   AAAAABBBCCCDEEEEEEHHHHHH    John AABBBCCCDEE
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work the way I want.

```
#!/user/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($infile1) = $ARGV[0];
my ($infile2) = $ARGV[1];
open(my $fh1, "<$infile1");

while(my $file1 = <$fh1> ){

my @file1 = split ("\t| ", $file1);
my $name_file1 = $file1[0];
my $ID_file1 = $file1[1];
my @matchline_file2 = `cat $infile2 | grep $name_file1`;
for my $ID_file1 (@file1){
        if (grep my $ID_file2 eq $ID_file1, @matchline_file2){
        print "found\n";}else{print "not_found\n";}}}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are after some rather complicated string comparison algorithm, if you want to choose the "best match".

Comment: @TLP I meant the best match according to the second column

Comment: So in each case is a line on file 1 a subset of a line in file2?

Comment: @ Jeef Yes, that's correct

Comment: @MaryamSani And by "best match" you mean the same type of matching, where one string is a substring of the other? You should probably elaborate on this, because it sounds like you provided way too little information.

Comment: @ TLP Correct. a substring of the other or completely the same string

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't print the results in reverse order like your output. I'm not sure if that was intentional. You could store the results in an array and reverse or sort the order if you like. Your example is very limited and this is just a best estimate of what you're trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($infile1) = $ARGV[0];
my ($infile2) = $ARGV[1];

my $search_file = "";
open(my $fh2, "<$infile2");

while(my $line = <$fh2>)
{
   $search_file .= $line;
}

open(my $fh1, "<$infile1");

while(my $line = <$fh1>)
{
   chomp($line);

   if($line =~ m/\w+\s+(.*)/)
   {
       my $search_string = quotemeta("$1");

       if($search_file =~ m/(.*$search_string.*)/)
       {
          print "$1\t$line\n";
       }
       else
       {
          print "Could not find: $line\n";
       }
   }
   else
   {
      print "Invalid line: $line\n";
   }
}
```

Comment: The [index()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) function can be used to find any occurrence of the substring `$needle` in the string `$haystack`. `index($haystack, $needle) >= 0`.

Comment: @chansen yes, but it seems easier to use the regular expression to get the entire line in which the substring occurred.

Comment: then you should quote/escape any meta characters when interpolating strings into regular expressions using the [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function or the `\Q ... \E` expression.

Comment: @chansen Thanks. I didn't think about that since this was a quick hash, but added it now.